# How to assign NA to "NO"

Tags: r, data-munging

In my dataset I have one column where I need to replace blanks to "No", How can I do this?

The column is a character variable and had only two values, yes and no.

```
data<- as.data.frame(Upper_GI_2ww)
data$`Direct to Test?` = ifelse(nchar(data$`Direct to Test?`) == "NA", "No",data$`Direct to Test? )
```

output:

```
head(data$`Direct to Test?`)
[1] "Yes" "Yes" "Yes" NA    "Yes" "Yes"
```

Soultion:

It is working fine now, Here is what i did:

First I have converted char to factor.

I used a simple is.na function

```
data$`Direct to Test?`[is.na(data$`Direct to Test?`)] <-"No"
head(data$`Direct to Test?`)
Yes Yes Yes No  Yes Yes
Levels: No Yes
```

it is working fine now.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Depending on your problem, it might also be safer/easy to say if not yes, then no

Comment: `df$col[df$col == ''] <- 'No'`

Comment: Not working with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nchar to count the number of characters.

```
df$var = ifelse(nchar(df$var) == 0, "No", df$var)
```

This is also valid if all you need is to replace "":

```
df$var = ifelse(df$var == "", "No", df$var)
```

Comment: Hello,

Thank you so much. Can I ask you why did you use nchar here ? because I did exactly the same without nchar and it was not working.

Comment: I use `nchar` because it counts the number of characters. 
Use `dput` to post your data

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you can do it with using the `sub()` function to replace empty strings

```
#create data
data <- c("", "yes", "", "no")

#make into data.frame
data <- as.data.frame(data)

#replacing empty strings with "No"
sub("^$", "No", data$data)
```

Comment: Hi Daniel,

Thanks for your comment but it is not working. Previously I had blanks but now it is showing me  "NA" using your code and replacing it with NA. nothing happens.

Comment: ```head(data$`Direct to Test?`)
[1] "Yes" "Yes" "Yes" NA    "Yes" "Yes"
```